# How to get particular object values and key values from JSON response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need to get Particular Object values ( A, B, C, D) and related key values (@"name" ). Here below I have posted my sample code and response. Please help me.

```
NSString *combined = URL;
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:combined];
NSData *responseData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *responsData = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"response"];

// GET A,B,C Object values
NSDictionary *d1 = responsData.firstObject;
NSEnumerator *enum1 = d1.keyEnumerator;
NSArray *firstObject = [enum1 allObjects];
```

My JSON Response :

```
response : [  {

                    A   =  [   {  
                             name : tango 
                               }
                           {
                            name : ping
                           }
                         ]

                    B  =  [   {  
                             name : tango 
                               }
                           {
                            name : ping
                           }
                        ]
                 } ]
```

Comment: You mean, for example, you need all `name`s of `A` ?

Comment: yes but without array brackets. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the list of all names using this:

```
NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in responsData) {

        [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
            NSArray *valueArray = (NSArray *)obj;

            for (NSDictionary * namesDict in valueArray) {
                [names addObject:namesDict[@"name"]];
            }
        }];
    }
```

Output:

```
NSLog(@"Names %@",names);
```

tango, ping, tango, ping.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow Your really great man Thought-Beast. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: @user3678460 name size?? If you are asking for count of names, should be super easy; `names.count`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in firstObject){
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But above i am getting and store A B C object seperatly then i checked by using for (firstObject in responsData) { }. here I can get the name value seperate array. I need to get without array bractes and list out all the name values.